# Keep getting this compiling error

Tags: c, cs50

When I compile, I keep getting this error.

```
mario.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '('
```

I've tried changing things and then fixing them and changing other things and then fixing those but nothing seems to help. I'm new at this. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void);
{
int n;

    do 
   { 
    n = GetInt();
   }
    while (n=<0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
int main(void);  
              ^Remove the semicolon
```

to

```
int main(void)
```

and also change

```
while (n=<0);
```

to

```
while (n <= 0);
```