# I keep getting this compiling error

Tags: c

When I complile, I keep getting this error.

mario.c:11:14: error: expected expression
    while (n=<0);
             ^

I've tried changing things and then fixing them and changing other things and then fixing those but nothing seems to help. I'm new at this. Can anyone help?

```
    do 
   { 
    n = GetInt();
   }
    while (n=<0);
```

Comment: n<=0 should be the text

Comment: say it out loud! greater than or equal (`<=`)

Comment: @meda; Its "less than or equal" :)

Comment: @haccks Oops , didnt get my coffee yet

Comment: Haven't you read carefully the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21914691/2455888) given to your previous question?

Comment: Before asking more questions, I would goto the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the `2 min tour` and read [about question bans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Answer (score 5):

`=<` is invalid syntax; you want `<=`, like this:

```
do 
{ 
    n = GetInt();
}
while (n<=0);
```